# how to handle the case when sObject= null

Tags: apex, visualforce

if a record exists, I want to render the stuff the `<apex:pageblock id = customList>`.  If it doesn't exist,i don't want to render that section.The code is not working when `variable = null`. I'm guessing I need  handle that scenerio differently. What do I do?

The error = `Error: Unknown property 'BytecodeApexObject.var_1__c`

```
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!NOT(numberExists)}">
    <center>
        <apex:commandButton value="Create Number & Strategies" action="{!createNewnumber}"/>
    </center>
</apex:pageBlock>


<apex:pageblock id="CustomList"  rendered="{!numberExists}">   
    <center>
        <apex:commandButton value="Edit Current number & Strategies"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Actions"/>
    </center>

    <apex:pageBlockSection >
         <apex:outputText value="{!variable.var_1__c}" label="V1"  escape="false"></apex:outputText>
         <apex:outputText value="{!variable.var2__c}" label="v2" escape="false"></apex:outputText>     
         <apex:outputText value="{!variable.var3__c}" label="v3" escape="false"></apex:outputText>     
         <apex:outputText value="{!variable.var4__c}" label="v4" escape="false"></apex:outputText>       
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
<apes:pageBlock>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class cPController {



public variable_analysis__c variable;
public CP__c mycP;  
public boolean numberExists;

//this method allows us to reference the current record selected by the user
public cPController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {        
    controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Account__c', 'Name'});
    this.mycP = (CP__c)controller.getRecord();    
    getvariable();        
    getnumberExists();     
}

public boolean getnumberExists(){
    if (variable == null){
        this.numberExists = false;
    }else{
        this.numberExists = true;
    }
    return this.numberExists;
}


    public void getvariable()   {
        try{
            if(this.variable==null){       
                this.variable= [select id,CP__c, var_1,var_2
                from variable_analysis__c 
                where CP__c=  :mycP.Id
                and Current_variable__c= true
                limit 1
                ];
            }
        }
        Catch (Exception e){
            this.variable = null;
        }         
    }


    public void setvariable(){        
        return;
    }


}

}//end of this controller class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public variable_analysis__c variable{get;set}; Use getter and Setter for variable
public boolean numberExists{get;set};Use getter and Setter
```

The problem i see is you need to make the variable getter setter if you are using on page .

Also i think in constructor you can declare as false and that would avoid null pointers

Explicitly you can also use this

```
rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(numberExists) , false , true)}"﻿﻿/>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the above details,

It is recommended not to use such a query when the record in any near to that because it will cause limits to pass especially if you DML with that condition. When the record count is huge use Batch Apex.

Thanks,
Subhani,
Salesforce Certified Developer,
www.mydbsync.com.